# Python: best practice for arguments that may or may not be lists

Tags: python

I have a method `foo(bar)` which has a loop in which by standard the argument `bar` is used as is in each iteration.

However, it is also possible to use different values of bar in each iteration. To allow for this I am currently checking whether `type(bar) in  (list, tuple)` (*). A pseudo-example of what I currently do is:

```
def foo(bar):
    #DETERMINE LENGTH L OF LOOP
    if not type(bar) in (list,tuple):
        bars=[bar]*L
    else:
        bars=bar
    for i in range(L):
        print(bars(i))
```

Is this approach considered good practice/pythonic? Would it be better to replace the argument `bar` by `bars`, i.e. force the user to pass a list of `bar`'s? Normally, I would go with this options, but passing different `bar`'s is required very seldomly, and `foo` is required so often that `foo([bar]*baz.bazz)` type calls would become quite a code pollution factor.

(*) I often read that instead I should be checking whether `bar` supports iteration. However, a single `bar` can support iteration as well.)

Comment: could you be a bit more clear on what you mean, and give a minimal example?

Comment: and you probably mean `type(bar) in (tuple, list)`, right?

Comment: @Maarten See the update

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, thanks

Comment: `if not type(bar) in (list,tuple):
        bars=[bar]*L` Where does L come from?

Comment: @Maarten it is determined in the commented out section of my pseudo-example, namely '#DETERMINE LENGTH L OF THE LOOP'. It doesn't make sense to reproduce this part of the code in full length, it suffices to know that L depends on the state of some object that is available to `foo`

Comment: you could have a helper method that always returned a list, returning the original list if it's an iterable and if not wrapping the single object in a list and returning that. Then you have no need to check the type of the object in the main foo method.

Comment: A slightly better condition for your if statement is: not isinstance(bar, (list, tuple))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried that `bar` might be iterable but not a `list` or `tuple`, for example a string, then you need to somehow check the type.

However `type(...) in (...)` isn't very pythonic, generally you'd use `isinstance` instead - because it also allows subclasses:

```
def foo(bar):
    #DETERMINE LENGTH L OF LOOP
    if not isinstance(bar, (list, tuple)):
        bars = [bar] * L
    else:
        bars = bar

    for i in range(L):
        print(bars[i])  # you wanted to index, right?
```

There's also `itertools.repeat` if you want to explicitly iterate over it without creating the full list up front:

```
import itertools

def foo(bar):
    #DETERMINE LENGTH L OF LOOP
    if not isinstance(bar, (list, tuple)):
        bars = itertools.repeat(bar, L)
    else:
        bars = bar

    for one_bar in bars:
        print(one_bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I really like about Python is that it's so composable. I'd move the repeating of items into its own function.

```
def sustain(items, L):
    for i in range(L):
        try:
            yield items[i]
        except TypeError:
            yield items
        except IndexError:
            yield items[-1]

def foo(bar):
    #DETERMINE LENGTH L OF LOOP
    for baz in sustain(bar, L):
        print(baz)

>>> list(sustain([1,2],2))
[1, 2]
>>> list(sustain([1,2],1))
[1]
>>> list(sustain([1,2],3))
[1, 2, 2]
>>> list(sustain(1,3))
[1, 1, 1]
```

The technique of using `try`/`except` to get different behaviors depending on the type is very Pythonic, it even has its own acronym: [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Comment: But `bar[i]` could exist even when `bar` is not a list

Comment: @Bananach yes, is there some part of my answer that doesn't work if that's the case?

Comment: If i underatand right, sustain would then iterate over a single bar,  if a single one and not a list was provided, and the error would only be noticed down the line outside of sustain

Comment: @Bananach but I thought that was the question you asked? It seems very clear from both the description and the code that you want to be able to pass a single `bar`, or a list or tuple of `bars`.

Comment: But for a single bar I want the code to recognize that it is a single bar, not return an entry of that single bar. Let's say bar can either be a string or a list of strings.if it is a single string,  I don't want to loop over each letter of that string but use that same string in every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0):

After some while I think it is best to either create two functions, e.g. `from_bar` and `from_bars`, or if `bar` is not an important enough parameter, then providing a switch (defaulting to `False`) to let `foo` know that multiple `bar`s are being passed, i.e. `foo(bar,multiple=False)`.

Note that both of these approaches go very well with the Python rule **explicit is better than implicit**